# NHibernate SessionFactory

Tags: nhibernate, session, performance

I just want to have this confirmed :

When working with NHibernate, I am expected to get a session from the session factory for each operation, right ?

Regards,
MadSeb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One session per transaction. For example one session per web-request in web-application.

Answer (score 7):

What's your definition of 'operation' ?
You can perform multiple actions within one session.   You should see the session as a [unit of work](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/unitOfWork.html).

Comment: for example....adding a new user to my users table ? that would require a new session right ?

Comment: Let's say it that way: for every operation that requires DB access by NH, you'll need to have a session.  The session can be seen as a unit-of-work, so everything that belongs together (logically), can be done in the same session.

Answer (score 0):

A good practice is to put the SessionFactory stuff into Global.asax

See http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/Configuring-NHibernate-with-ASP-NET.aspx for detailled informations